# Unable to do sfdx deploy or sfdx retrieve from Vs code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, git

I reinstalled git as I thought my git became corrupt, git doesnt have issue as git log and git status commands work. My VS code is connected to a sandbox, whenever I am doing a sfdx deploy source to org command, or a sfdx retrieve source from org command I am getting the below error:

An internal error caused this command to fail. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git/issues with this error message: Index file is empty (.git/index)

I restarted Vs code, reinstalled git. Nothing is working

**-- UPDATE--**

Got the solution. The latest Salesforce CLI Extension for VS code version 58.13.1 has issues. When I downgraded it to version 57.10.2 it worked. It was not a git issue as git cli commands were working.

Comment: It worked for me , thanks !!!!

Comment: Can you post your update as an answer instead? It's perfectly to answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer too.